# When can I use the natural log to help solve an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms

Why is it okay to do this: $\int \frac{1}{x-2}dx = \ln(x-2)$

but not this: $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx   = \ln(1-x^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule is the difference.  Note that $\int\frac{du}{u}=\ln|u|$.  So, you must have a fraction of the form $u$ on the bottom and the derivative of $u$ on the top.  For your second example, $u=1-x^2$, but $du=-2xdx$ is not the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

Because the derivative of $\ln(f(x))$ is not $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ for all differentiable function $f$, even if it is true for $f(x)=x-a$ where $a$ is a constant.

The derivative of $\ln(f(x))$ is $\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}$ applying the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

The first integral can be solved by *linear* substitution $z = x - 2$.

The second one is non-linear and does not work. Instead you have
$-2 \, \int x/(1-x^2) = \mathrm{ln}(1-x^2) + C$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try differentiating your second expression on both sides, utlizing FTC.